# Trace import of a certain css with Firebug

Tags: css, firebug

I am having an interesting problem debugging a css issue with Firebug. I have a page that looks "different" from the rest of the site. When I check in Firebug, one of the imported CSS files does not appear on any other page, so I removed it within Firebug and the layout issues are resolved...

So far so good, I identified the intruder file... The issue is, that I can't find the import anywhere in the workspace... Even if I check the page source code, it's not there, so I'm assuming it's getting imported the '@import' statement indirectly from some of the imported css files (nested twice or more since I can't seem to find the import anywhere I look)...

My concrete question is, is there a way to make Firebug show where a loaded resource in a page comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Referer` header of the requested CSS file indicates were it was imported. You can see that header by switching to the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel), reloading the page and expanding the request to the "intruder file".

There's also a [request for better indication of the initiator of a request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=1772), though this requires [platform support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=563623).

Sebastian

Comment: Wow, nice Workaround. I had already found the error, but now I tried with some other page and it does exactly what I was expecting... With complex sites it saves a lot of time...